# MySQL Workbench 8.0 : no connection established and could not acquire management access for administration

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm very new in the IT world, and I've just started learning SQL.
I'm working on MySQL Workbench, and I already did some work in it (creating databases etc...) but since I've restarted my computer (and nothing else), I cannot access it anymore.

-First problem : no connection established (a frequent solution to this problem I found is to go to Services, find "Mysql56" and clic on start, however I do not see Mysql56 there)

-Second problem : when the "Administrator" tab pops up, I have this message : "could not acquire management access for administration. Runtime Error : Unable to execute command chcp. Please make sure that the C:\Windows\System32 directory is in your PATH environment variable.

-Third error that appears when I input password for root and Test connection is : "Unhandled exception : current profile has no WMI enabled".

Any help would be welcome, I've spent hours trying to find a solution on forums, nothing so far.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

- If you do not find MySQL in the service section, you must delete it completely once, make sure that it is completely removed from all systems.
  Note that it is possible to delete information on MySQL.
  This was a good route for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue when I disabled all services on windows 11,
[system configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1J66.png) 
and enabled those services, then it working..